# Shopify buy-button-js: How to add multiple buttons with different buttonDestinations

Tags: shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template, shopify-storefront-api

I am trying implementing the Shopify **buy-button-js** on my homepage.
The problem: I want to display multiple buttons with different buttonDestination for each product in the collection **and** additionally make the product clickable.
E.g.: Product -> Open modal & Add to cart & Buy now.

Is there an easy way to solve the problem with the Shopify **buy-button-js** library?